# Trigger a github workflow on target branch changed

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a github workflow that runs a labeler pull-requests based on the changed files: https://github.com/actions/labeler

Sometimes, the user that opens the PR forgets to set the correct target branch, which results with labels that correspond to the wrong target branch. After opening the PR, the user changes to the correct target branch but doesn't trigger the labeler again. I was wondering if github provides an option to trigger a workflow on the event of target branch change?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the base of a pull request triggers a `pull_request` event, of type `edited`. By default, `pull_request` events trigger, if not further specified, on `open`, `synchronize`, and `reopened` (see [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request)). To also trigger on `edited`, the trigger has to look something like this:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
      - reopened
      - edited
```

This behaves like the default behaviour plus `edited`.

Generally, if you'd like to see what webhooks are exactly triggered when you do something, you can use the official [GitHub CLI webhooks extension](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/testing-and-troubleshooting-webhooks/using-the-github-cli-to-forward-webhooks-for-testing) for debugging.

Comment: There is a typo in this answer - it should be `opened`, not `open`. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request